# How to count total number of users from database table using JPA, Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, count, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get total number of mu users from database table. I am using Spring-boot, JPA and Hibernate as provider. I am trying to get total number of users that I have stored in database table and display it in my index.html. Also I would like to do the same with my other tables classes and professors.

**HomeController.java**

```
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private ClassesRepository classesRepository;

        @Autowired
        private ProfessorRepository professorRepository;

        @Autowired
        private PostRepository repository;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
        public String dashboardPageListClasses(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("classes", classesRepository.findAll());
            model.addAttribute("user", userRepository.findAll());
            model.addAttribute("professor", professorRepository.findAll());
            return "dashboard";
        }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="card-content">
    <p class="category">Students</p>
    <h3 class="title">**I would like to display total number here**</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: this may help  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tipstricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrudRepository provides a count api to count the records
all you need is to add this to your controller

```
  model.addAttribute("count", professorRepository.count());
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I added like this for 3 different counts: `model.addAttribute("countClasses", classesRepository.count());`,  `model.addAttribute("countUser", userRepository.count());`,  `model.addAttribute("countProfesor", profesorRepository.count());`

Answer (score 2):

You can use CrudRepository default function

> `long count()`
>
> Returns the number of entities available.

or write Custom Query

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u")
    Long countUsers();

}
```

Comment: Yes that is also way to do it. It is working. I added `model.addAttribute("countUsers", userRepository.countUsers());` to my controller and that was it.